# Prove claims about disjoint union and decidable/undecidable languages

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Let $L\subseteq\Sigma^*$ decidable language and $A\subseteq\Sigma^*$.

Let $B=A\sqcup L$ (a ***disjoint*** union).

Prove:

$1$. $B\in RE \Rightarrow A\in RE$

$2$. $B\in R \Rightarrow A\in R$

Thanks!

Comment: What are your thoughts? Try to express $A$ in terms of $B$ and $L$ using set-theoretic operations.

Comment: for 2: $B\in RE \Rightarrow A\sqcup L\in RE \Rightarrow\;\text{there is a decidable TM M for}\; A\sqcup L \Rightarrow\;\text{M is a decidable TM for A}\Rightarrow\;\text{we can use M as a decidable TM for A}\;\,\,\Rightarrow A\in R $
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B = A \sqcup L$ then $A = B \cap \overline{L}$, where $\overline{L} = \Sigma^* \setminus L$. Note that $\overline{L}$ is decidable. The classes $R$ and $RE$ are closed under finite intersections (and unions also). Hence if $B \in RE$ (or $B \in R)$ then (since we also have $\overline{L} \in R \subset RE$) it holds that $A = B \cap \overline{L} \in RE$ (or $B \cap \overline{L} \in R$ respectively).